# Symbols Missing for nsiCookieManager2 program

Tags: firefox, xul

Please help me with the missing LIBs for this MOZILLA program.
Trying to create cookie using nsICookieManager2
I have tried with all the existing libs in Mozilla SDK
Regards

> C:\Code>cl.exe FFCookie.cpp /I "C:\xulrunner-sdk\include" mozalloc.lib  xpcomglue.lib /link /LIBPATH:"C:\xulrunner-sdk\lib"

Symbols Missing:

> FFCookie.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void
>   __thiscall nsCOMPtr_base::assign_from_gs_contractid_with_er ror(class nsGetServiceByContractIDWithError const &,struct nsID const &)"
>   (?assign_from_gs_contractid_with_error@nsCOMPtr_base@@QA
>   EXABVnsGetServiceByContractIDWithError@@ABUnsID@@@Z) referenced in
>   function "public: __thiscall nsCOMPtr::
>   nsCOMPtr(class
>   nsGetServiceByContractIDWithError const &)"
>   (??0?$nsCOMPtr@VnsICookieManager@@@@QAE@ABVnsGe
>   tServiceByContractIDWithError@@@Z)
>
> FFCookie.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void
>   __thiscall nsCOMPtr_base::assign_from_qi(class nsQueryInter face,struct nsID const &)"
>   (?assign_from_qi@nsCOMPtr_base@@QAEXVnsQueryInterface@@ABUnsID@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: __t hiscall nsCOMPtr::nsCOMPtr(class
>   nsQueryInterface)" (??0?$nsCOMPtr@VnsICookieMan
>   ager2@@@@QAE@VnsQueryInterface@@@Z) FFCookie.exe : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

```c++
#include "nsICookieManager.h"
#include "nsICookieManager2.h"
#include "nsServiceManagerUtils.h"
#include "nsComPtr.h"
#include "nsNetCID.h"
#include "nsStringAPI.h"
#include "mozilla-config.h"
int main()
{

    nsresult rv;
    nsCOMPtr<nsICookieManager> cookieManager = do_GetService (NS_COOKIEMANAGER_CONTRACTID, &rv);
     NS_ENSURE_SUCCESS(rv, rv);

    if (cookieManager)
    {
      nsCOMPtr<nsICookieManager2> cookieManager2 = do_QueryInterface(cookieManager);
      if (cookieManager2)
      {
        cookieManager2->Add(NS_LITERAL_CSTRING("ud.abc.com"),
                       NS_LITERAL_CSTRING("//"),
                       NS_LITERAL_CSTRING("TK"),
                       NS_LITERAL_CSTRING("abc"),  0x1, 0x1, 0, -1);

      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Questions:

I dont find any info with function documentation regarding which LIB to include (as I find on MSDN)

Any clue on how to figure out LIB corresponding to particular function for MOZILLA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with the lib, the symbol missing is defined in the `xpcomglue` library. However, you seem to have some compile parameters that don't match the parameters used to compile XULRunner/Firefox. The symbols your compiler is looking for contain "QAEX" as parameter description whereas the library defines them with "QAIX". Looking at [the name mangling table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Name_Mangling#Data_Type), your compiler expects `unsigned char` where Mozilla has `unsigned int`. I suspect that the reason is you compiling your application without Unicode support - change `main()` into `wmain()`?

Comment: I tried changing the main() to wmain() with UNICODE flag but still problem is not resolved

Comment: Thank you for your analytical inputs. Really appreciate them. I was missing some hash defs XP_WIN and XP_WIN32